# Hyperledger Fabric Rocksdb Database, Retrieve and Modification

Tags: database, security, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, rocksdb

I am working around to figure out that Fabric v0.6 is really not allowed data modification illegally. Beside I want to modify data in "sst" format directly. I want to use some other such as create instance of database then retrieve all data -> Modified them -> put them back and star the peer normally. but when I try to create instance of Rocksdb, I got this error

[Rocksdb Error Column Family Not opened...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sddeb.png)

Based on this tutorial: http://pyrocksdb.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4/tutorial/index.html

If it's a new database then it's fine. while it come to database of blockchain, I got this few error.

Comment: do u solve this problem? I want to modify data however I delete whole db and nothing happens..

Comment: Not yet, but some of my friends can do that

Comment: Oops...Do they have any ideas to share?